# How to join Queue(Of String) as a string?

Tags: .net, vb.net, join

I have following code:

```
Dim PendingFiles As New Queue(Of String)
```

I need to join each element of PendingFiles with a comma and store the result as a string. How do I achieve it?

Something like this:

```
Dim Result As String
Result = Join(PendingFiles, ",")
'NOTE: this the way if PendingFiles is a string array. 
'      But now, it is Queue(Of String). So how do I join it?
```

Comment: Result = Join(PendingFiles.ToList(), ",")

Comment: @asawyer: Your answer didn't work

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`String.Join<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) method:

```
Result = String.Join(",", PendingFiles);
```

Comment: is there a .NET 2.0 solution for this?

Comment: Check my solution for `.NET 2.0`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.NET 2.0` then @jason solution won't work.

Try this instead:

```
Result = String.Join(",", PendingFiles.ToArray());
```

Why would you use `.NET 2.0` ? One example is for API compatibility in Unity3D.